# window.location.reload() after jQuery.get() not executing script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script:

```
function upvote() {
    $.get('includes/upvote.php?id=page1&name=HybridFox');
    window.location.reload();
    return false;
}
```

When i use this, the script (includes/upvote.php) isnt getting executed. But the page is getting reloaded.
the upvote.php contains a php script that inserts `$_GET["name"]` into a database

I'm sorry if this is a stupid mistake i'm just overlooking, but i really can't fine what is wrong

Comment: You need to wait for the async request to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for request to finish. jQuery aborts all pending XMLHttpRequest on page unload to avoid memory leaks in IE. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/h75Ky/2/

```
function upvote() {
    $.get('includes/upvote.php?id=page1&name=HybridFox').always(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: it isnt refreshing now :/ neither executing the code

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "includes/upvote.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { id: page1, name: HybridFox },
}).done(function( html ) {
    $( "SOMEDIV" ).append( html );
  });
```

At least thats the way i'd do it since i'd assume you're going to want the results. I'm on my mobile at the moment so the code is untested but can check it when I get home.